# How can I program a custom optional command, so that the method is then executed multiple times

Tags: c

I have a main function like so:

```
main{
//do something;
}
```

How can I program the makefile, so that in the command line, when I enter `make main -P<Int>`, then the main is executed  amount of times. I do this to check multiple performances and time for execution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to exclude *make* from your need? Just by typing `main -P<Int>` for instance?

Comment: Im not very experienced in the makefile, but could you describe how it could works?

Comment: It's not actually clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to run the executable N times or do you want the executable to run once but internally loop N times?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude *make* from the equation, this can be done at C level.

In C, the *main()* function takes two arguments:

- *int argc*: is the number of command line arguments,
- *char ** argv*: is the list of these command line arguments.

The following source code shows how this works:

```
$ cat main.c
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    printf ( "Number of arguments: %d\n", argc );
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "  argument #%d: '%s'\n", i, argv[i] );
    }
    return 0; // main() returns an int which may be handled by the calling process
}
```

Compile it (in this case, *make* is able to work without a *Makefile*):

```
$ make main
```

And execute it:

```
$ ./main foo
```

Result is:

```
Number of arguments: 2
  argument #0: './main'
  argument #1: 'foo'
```

You will need to convert a string to an int: a simple function is [atoi()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html).